# php op code cache not working

Tags: php, caching

i installed php op code cache. php -v produces correct output, showing eaccelerator. but phpinfo() shows:

eAccelerator

eAccelerator support    enabled

Version 0.9.6.1

Caching Enabled false

Optimizer Enabled   false

Check mtime Enabled false

i tried putting it as zend or php extension into php.ini ... same result ... checked paths ... all correct ... instructions are in this file ... http://www.eaccelerator.net/wiki/InstallFromSource

how can i get it work? thanks

Comment: Are you bound to eAccelerator or are you fine with an alternative like APC?

Comment: Did you get it to work? I have the same problem here, all is checked, but still can't get it to cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to compiling the module, you need to ensure that you configure the settings of the module in the php.ini to enable it. Please double-check that you have actually **enabled** the module. The loading of the module already seems to work according to your question.

```
eaccelerator.shm_size="16"
eaccelerator.cache_dir="/tmp/eaccelerator"
eaccelerator.enable="1"
eaccelerator.optimizer="1"
eaccelerator.check_mtime="1"
eaccelerator.debug="0"
eaccelerator.filter=""
eaccelerator.shm_max="0"
eaccelerator.shm_ttl="0"
eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="0"
eaccelerator.shm_only="0"
eaccelerator.compress="1"
eaccelerator.compress_level="9"
```

Comment: extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613"
extension="eaccelerator.so"
eaccelerator.shm_size="16"
eaccelerator.cache_dir="/tmp/eaccelerator"
eaccelerator.enable="1"
eaccelerator.optimizer="1"
eaccelerator.check_mtime="1"
eaccelerator.debug="0"
eaccelerator.filter=""
eaccelerator.shm_max="0"
eaccelerator.shm_ttl="0"
eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="0"
eaccelerator.shm_only="0"
eaccelerator.compress="1"
eaccelerator.compress_level="9"

Comment: does it have any sort of error log ... not sure what the issue is

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't copy the file into the standard extension dir? Or is that your standard extension dir? Error log: If PHP could not load the extension, there would be an error. However from your question I would say the extension is successfully loaded but it's features are not enabled. I have never used that extension, so no own experiences here. Please see as well my comment below you question reg. alternative Opcode caches.

Comment: Mine is enabled in php.ini and shows up in phpinfo() but eAccelerator support enabled / Version 0.9.6.1 / Caching Enabled **false** / Optimizer Enabled **false** / Check mtime Enabled **false**. I'm going nuts with this.